# RegEx for matching commas inside array values

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to parse a CSV file line by line

```
String rowStr = br.readLine();
```

When i tried printing the rowStr i see the below

```
"D","123123","JAMMY,"," ","PILOT"
```

How can i remove the comma from a value field? I want to **retain** the commas outside.

Comment: I'm tempted to say regex

Answer (score 2):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/uPWvvJ/1) might help you to do so, however it may be unnecessary to do this task with regular expressions. If yet you wish/have to do so:

```
(")([A-z0-9\s]+)([,]?)(",)?
```

I have added boundaries, just to be safe. You can much simplify it. The key is to add a capturing group before and one after the values.

[image]

For instance, one boundary is that, in case you might accidentally have extra commas that are not values, it won't capture that

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Java Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(\")([A-z0-9\\s]+)([,]?)(\",)?";
final String string = "\"D\",\"123123\",\"JAMMY,\",\" \",\"PILOT\"";
final String subst = "\\1\\2 \\4";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

#### JavaScript Test Demo

```js
const regex = /(")([A-z0-9\s]+)([,]?)(",)?/gm;
const str = `"D","123123","JAMMY,"," ","PILOT"`;
const subst = `$1$2 $4`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Performance Test

```js
repeat = 1000000;
start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 var string = '"D","123123","JAMMY,"," ","PILOT"';
 var regex = /(")([A-z0-9\s]+)([,]?)(",)?/gm;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$1$2$4");
}

end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Comment: It wouldn't match where a field *begins* with a comma, as in `"FOO","BAR",",<-HERE"`. Though you provided Java code so it's a way more comprehensive answer than mine

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex like this:

`(?<!"),|,(?!")`

Matches a comma not preceded ***or*** not followed by a `"`.
Test [here](https://regexr.com/4dks2).